Multiple address would not display
Is the code below correct? it is not showing the full address when displayed.

1) $sys.func.TO_TEXT($sys.func.GET($sys.func.SPLIT($session.params.wh-nbn-services[0].address, ","),0))
2) $sys.func.TO_TEXT($sys.func.GET($sys.func.SPLIT($session.params.wh-nbn-services[1].address, ","),0))

How do we Split the address using the right most comma?
For Example: address is "unit 1, Glory Road, Sydney NSW"
Expected output should be "unit 1, Glory Road"

Can you please add an example how wh-nbn-services looks like?

Hi Florian, thanks for the response. We used a webhook to grab the complete address (i.e. Unit #, Street Name, Suburb, State). We just need to show up until the Suburb part. For now the code that we used only shows the first 2 lines of the address. Example are on the image that I attached.

Hi Team, just to clarify the question, how do we Split the address using the right most comma?
For Example: address is "unit 1, Glory Road, Sydney"
Expected output should be " unit 1, Glory Road
